# Trying to capture an specific part of a hidden window

Tags: c#, .net, gdi, user32

Been losing some days on this, I'm trying to capture an specific part of a hidden window, like per example, capture only coordinates 300, 300 to 350, 350. I'm trying to do some image recognition and using a full screenshot takes too long to find matches. Below is the code I'm using to capture a region:

```cs
public class WindowCapture
{
    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);
    }
    
    private class GDI32
    {
        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
            int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
            int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
            int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }

    public Image CaptureWindowRegion(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(hWnd);

        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref windowRect);

        int originalwidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int originalheight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

        CropRect(ref windowRect, x, y, w, h);

        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, originalwidth, originalheight);

        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);

        User32.PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcDest, 0);

        IntPtr hdcDest2 = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDest);
        IntPtr hBitmap2 = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDest, width, height);
        IntPtr hOld2 = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest2, hBitmap2);

        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest2, 0, 0, width, height, hdcDest, x, y, GDI32.SRCCOPY);

        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest2, hOld2);

        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest2);
        User32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcSrc);

        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap2);

        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap2);

        return img;
    }

    private static void CropRect(ref User32.RECT windowRect, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        windowRect.left = (x > 0) ? Math.Min(windowRect.right, windowRect.left + x) : windowRect.left;
        windowRect.right = (w > 0) ? Math.Min(windowRect.right, windowRect.left + w) : windowRect.right;
        windowRect.top = (y > 0) ? Math.Min(windowRect.bottom, windowRect.top + y) : windowRect.top;
        windowRect.bottom = (h > 0) ? Math.Min(windowRect.bottom, windowRect.top + h) : windowRect.bottom;
    }
}
```

After researching a bunch, all I could manage was a smaller all black bitmap.
Any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Get child windows.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindow

Comment: @jdweng I tried with a child window handle but no luck, the code above is working, but i need to crop the image, which i tried extensively but ultimately couldnt do it.

Comment: How do you know where to crop?  Either you need to use a child window or do a recognition.  I would check all children and location of the children to get better understanding of the view.

Comment: Im going to edit my question with the function im trying to use to capture+crop.

Comment: @jdweng edited. The window only has one child.

Comment: Does it work if you *don't* crop? If not: (1) `PrintWindow` eventually ends up in `WM_PRINTCLIENT`, which is optional for windows to implement. If your target window doesn't implement it, `PrintClient` has no chance of helping you. (2) If you are trying to capture a game for example, copying from the target window's DC won't get you anywhere because that only works if the window is actually rendered using classic GDI. Capturing hardware accelerated render target surfaces is a very, *very* complex topic, you may need to check out the source code of OBS studio for example.